# How is Socket working in Java?

Tags: java, sockets

i want to know the functionality of sockets in java. when i am creating some http-server i can use some ready to use sockets for secure and non-secure communication between two parties. but i never installed tomcat to my project, so my question is: how can java create a tcp / ip connection without a web-server? Can someone post me some link to clear this question?

In my case i used this to create a SSLSocket:

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;


import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory;


public class MainClass {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
  SSLServerSocketFactory ssf = (SSLServerSocketFactory)SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
  ServerSocket ss = ssf.createServerSocket(5432);
  while (true) {
    Socket s = ss.accept();
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
    out.println("Hi");
    out.close();
    s.close();
  }
 }
}
```

Thank u a lot,
   Mira

Comment: Maybe you start by studying the basics; and the layers involved. Hint: TCP/IP is the protocol ... that all those webbish things build upon. In other words: don't ask how Java implements Sockets. Instead; ask the net: "what are sockets? What is tcp/ip?" and so on; as your question implies that you have not much of an idea about the things you are talking about.

Comment: To add to GhostCat comment, Tomcat, Apache, and other "Web-Servers" are tools, that create a functional system, they usually use TCP/IP method, to provide mostly HTML content. They create Sockets, on defined ports, that allow other computers to agree on them, and create facilities for communication. [Wikipedia can show you some agreed upon ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers)

Comment: Thank u for the first impression. I think it is a good idea to learn about how tcp/ip works. Lots of people are using this examples and have no idea what is happing there. (Like me)